# Java Try-catch block, Catch block does not re-prompt the user for a new value

Tags: java, try-catch

I am new to Java and would like to ask you a question.

I have written the below code where "`numOfThreads`" should be assigned a valid int value by the user through the Console.

However, I would like to achieve a result where if the input is incorrect and we go in the catch block, the user should be re-prompted to enter "`numOfThreads`" until it is of correct type and range.

For some reason I seem to go into infinite loop. Can you please assist? Thanks :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        int numOfThreads;
        boolean promptUser = true;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (promptUser)
        {
            try{
                numOfThreads = keyboard.nextInt();
                promptUser = false;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Entry is not correct and the following exception is returned: " + e);
                numOfThreads = keyboard.nextInt(); // DOES NOT SEEM TO BE ASKING FOR A NEW INPUT
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `nextInt()` throws an exception, it doesn't consume the token... so calling `nextInt` again is just going to throw again.

Comment: Your try/catch is pretty useless... What if they input a wrong input when you reprompt?

Answer (score 3):

it doesn´t because `nextInt` tries to consume the last token. When there is an invalid input it can´t consume it. As a result a following `nextInt` call wont be able to consume it either. write a `keyboard.nextLine` before `numOfThreads = keyboard.nextInt();` and you are fine.

```
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Entry is not correct and the following exception is returned: " + e);
    // this consumes the invalid token now
    keyboard.nextLine();
    numOfThreads = keyboard.nextInt(); // It wasn´t able to get the next input as the previous was still invalid
    // I´d still rewrite it a little bit, as this keyboard.nextInt is now vulnerable to throw a direct exception to the main
}
```